# Как разбить строку по запятой, кроме случая когда за ней следует пробел?

Tags: java, split

Есть строка 1,2,3,"4, A",B, 5,C,6,7,8. Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее разбить на подстроки по запятой но пропустив запятую + пробел? Ниже код который работает, может есть более простой вариант?

```
String s = "1,2,3,\"4, A\",B, 5,C,6,7,8";
String[] ss;
s = s.replaceAll(", ", "#%&"); // меняем "запятая + пробел" на любой символ
ss = s.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ss[i].replaceAll("#%&", ", ")); // возвращаем запятую с пробелом обратно
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Т.к. `split` принимает регулярное выражение, то можно использовать [просмотр вперед с отрицанием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4):

```
String[] ss = s.split(",(?!\\s)");
```

Выражение `,(?!\s)` означает: «запятая, если за ней не следует пробельный символ». Пробельный символ может быть любой, если нужно игнорировать именно пробел, то укажите его явно:

```
String[] ss = s.split(",(?! )");
```